# Detecting duplicates in a file

Tags: java, c++, mysql, database, sqlite

I am attempting to develop an application that would parse in a file (i.e comma,tab delimited) and find duplicate entries. The duplicate entries need to be written to a separate file, with the original input file remaining as is. The problem I am having is I can't come to a decision on how I should actually find those matches ?

Lets assume data is as follows:

```
id,Firstname,Lastname,Address,Country
1,James,Michael,123 St,USA
2,James,Michae l,123 St,AU
3,Steve,Smith,12445,UK
```

*The rule is that two records are considered duplicates only if `firstname,lastname,address` match (keeping in mind that spaces can't be considered in the algorithm)

Here are the questions I am struggling with

1. Does it make any difference if I use something like sqlite then query for duplicates rather than use the native language of the application (i.e c++,java,python) ?
2. Given that the record quantities may range between 1000-1000000 which data structures,functions,etc can be used to reduce execution time ?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Question 2 "what are some ways..." and question 3 are not appropriate here.  They are too broad and chatty.  Can you [edit] your question so it asks a clear, specific question that would have a correct answer?

Comment: In response to #2: You might try using a hash table to store references to entries. That way, you can simply compute the hash of each entry,store a reference to the corresponding entry in a hash table according to the hash, and look for matches to each entry among the entries that match the hash you calculated. 

This should cut down considerably on computation time, as you won't be attempting to compare every entry with every other entry. [Hash functions in c++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) and [hash tables in c++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: @DrewDormann updated the question, is it clearer now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heres how I would do it. 
Create a Person class which holds those members (firstname,lastname,address,...)
override the toString() to return a unique string, you'll also need to override equals() and hashCode() for your person class.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
return firstname+lastname+address;
}
```

then you need a bucket(s) to hold those object, use key value datastructure lika a Map.

```
Map<String, Person>
```

then you'll simply use the toString of your object as keys, and the object itself as the values.

When processing the bucket, probably in a loop you'll have to check if you're bucket already contains a duplicate of that person object something like this?

```
    /*look for duplicates*/
    for (Person obj : allPersonsList) {
        if (uniquePersonMap.containsKey(obj.toString())) {
            Person previousPerson = uniquePersonMap
                      .get(obj.toString();
\\do something with previous or current person object
            }
            uniquePersonMap.put(obj.toString();
```

HashMap will be fast enough to get objects based on their hash value but havin 5000000 records, you probably would run into some preformance issues or out of memory issues so you would want to hold on to as little obj as possible any given time
hope this helps 
happy coding

Comment: would it make much of a difference if the `toString` method had a `trim` or `replace` ?

Comment: you just want it to be unique based on those attributes mentionen, whatever works for you.